# How to add android studio library

Tags: java, android, picker

may some one explain me how can I add a library to my android studio's project?

This is the library: https://github.com/code-troopers/android-betterpickers

I'd like to use the recurrence picker. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[image]

open this file and inside of it, you will find the following the icon on the side might not be the same

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.code-troopers.betterpickers:library:3.1.0' //add this line here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this library as dependency in your project (assume you use android studio) Add this dependency in your **gradle** build script:

```
 dependencies {  
        compile group: 'com.code-troopers.betterpickers', name: 'library', version: '3.1.0'
}
```

Comment: I've already done that. I get these errors: http://mygym2017.altervista.org/Screenshot__14_.png

Answer (score 0):

You need this dependency, which you can find below all the screenshots in your link

[image]

Then find this file in your project:

[image]

Put your dependecy in the dependencies block:

[image]

After that you will see the message that gradle files have changed and a project sync is necessary. Press on Sync Now